# Как правильно получить данные webhook через ASP.NET core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, бот, viber

не могу понять, как правильно получить данные в ASP.net core api post запросе, какие-то примеры находил, не пойму, как написать, чтобы контроллер принимал callback от viber, обычные запросы делаю и получаю ответ, при регистрации бота указывал ссылку на свой сайт для webhook, чтобы получать callback.
Или может по-другому можно бот сделать для Viber?
Кто знает, опишите, пожалуйста, с этими сетями слаб, а нужно как-то настроить, если можно примеры, чтобы понял наконец. Спасибо
Если что ссылка на документацию - https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#callbacks

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А почему вы решили, что у вас код нерабочий? Если вы поставили вебхук, задеплоили вот это код, который ничего не делает -- то откуда уверенность, что это "не работает"? На вебсервере видно, что приходит POST-запрос? Видно содержимое JObject?

Comment: Что именно у вас "не работает"? В том малом куске кода который вы дали - все вполне корректно. Сервер на котором размешено ваше приложение обрабатывающее callback-и от Viber-а точно ли доступен извне? Либо может некорректно был указан url при вызове set_webhook для регистрации вебхука?

Comment: url указан правильно, мне приходит код 0 - ок, я не могу вывести переменную event, я ее не вижу, events выводится в другом методе, но он не перезаписывается даже, может проблема и в этом, как тогда правильно вывести?

Comment: я проверил через postman сайт и post запрос был, если вы пишите, что в asp post запрос правильный, то значит дело в выводе значения, подскажите, а как вывести правильно, не делая пока десериализацию, обычный json вывести. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, надеюсь, кому-то пригодится, и он будет мучиться меньше, чем я))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] JObject data)
    {
       Message.Result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
        //Task<string> dataToString = Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data));
        //Task<CallBack> callBack = Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallBack>(dataToString.Result));
      string dataToString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
       Task<CallBack> callBack =Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallBack>(dataToString));
        await Task.Run(() => Initialization.CallBackInitializationAsync= callBack);


        // Message.Result= Request.Headers["X-Viber-Content-Signature"];

        if (callBack.Result.Event == EventType.ConversationStarted)
        {
            viber = new Viber(callBack.Result);
            viber.Start();
            await viber.SendTextMessageAsync();
        }
        return Ok();

    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оформляйте код в вопросах и ответах текстом, а не картинкой. Не обрекайте других пользователей на перепечатывание вашего кода вручную :)

Comment: @PashaPash хорошо, учту)